# Barcode Scanning for MC55 series handhelds with C++

Tags: c++, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I have an old application originally written to run on windows CE, which should run on MC55A0 and does not.
It will currently run on an MC65, but these are apparently at end of life.

The EMDK 2.7 for C does not even know what an MC55 is.

Also, the EMDK only works with  VS2008, which is not longer supported, but I have managed to download a trial version anyway.

It looks like the barcode library I was using (scnapi32.lib) is not longer supported.

The question is: has anyone had any luck getting a barcode scanning app in C++ to run on an MC55A0, (and if so, how?) or should I just bite the bullet and port to C#?

Comment: Problem was not with the scanning api, but an odd collection of configuration issues. The lack of meaningful error messages did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of Zebra's EMDK for C support MC55A:

- [EMDK for C
  v2.8](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97037&productDetailGUID=1a45d085364cf310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD)

The EMDK works only with Visual Studio 2005 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008 because these are the compilers that supports Windows CE/Windows Mobile. Newer compilers doesn't support these operative systems.

Building an application in C++ targeting an MC55A0 is possible, and you can start from the sample application included in the EMDK.

If the application is currently running on an MC65, you can take a look at the [MC67](https://www.zebra.com/mc67) that is the natural evolution of the MC65 (and it's a WWAN device, MC55A0 is only WIFI).

Comment: Thanks. I had managed to get everything working, but a combination of coding errors and configuration issues made it quite a slog. I had not realised that they were insisting on 2008 because of support for Windows Mobile... I don't suppose you know what the logical successor of these platforms is? Documentation seems light on the ground.

Comment: I do know a lot about this (disclaimer, I work for Zebra Technologies). Windows Mobile/Windows CE are a dead end with support ending in 2020/2021. Microsoft released in 2015 Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld that was the enterprise version of Windows Phone 8.1. Complete different OS from Windows Mobile and application not compatible (less that 20% of API from WM are in WE8.1H). The next iteration is Windows 10 IoT Enterprise Mobile. Another different OS. Zebra started to work in 2011 with Android. Nowadays, with [iFactr](http://ifactr.com/), you can have your WM app supported on Android.